# Windows Phone 8.1 app MediaCapture under exposed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, camera, media, image-capture

I am trying to capture pictures directly from the camera in my Windows Phone 8.1 Store App.

I have succeeded in initializing a `MediaCapture` for the device and it take photographs but they are always black or way way under exposed.

Can someone point me in the direction of how I get the camera to auto expose and if possible trigger a focus too as I get catastrophic failure when I call `photoManager.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusAsync()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For auto-focus I use this code:

```
mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
settings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video;
settings.PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview;

await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);

var focusSettings = new FocusSettings();
focusSettings.AutoFocusRange = AutoFocusRange.FullRange;
focusSettings.Mode = FocusMode.Auto;
focusSettings.WaitForFocus = true;
focusSettings.DisableDriverFallback = false;

mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Configure(focusSettings);
```

for exposure, try this:

```
await mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.ExposureControl.SetAutoAsync(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the focus tip. That works great but still no luck with the autoexpose.

Comment: Somehow, i cant find neither FocusSettings nor FocusControl.Configure() in Wp 8.1 unified.

Comment: Are you creating an Universal (WinRT) application? Those should be present in the Windows.Media.Devices namespace.

Comment: Hey Jogy, I am trying to do the same with a Javascript/Cordova application application without much luck.
I was wondering if you could take a look at [this source code](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/blob/master/src/windows/BarcodeScannerProxy.js) and tell me if you see something wrong. In [this bug](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/41) I'm discussing why is the autofocus not working, but I have not been able to figure out the source :/.
Any help is much welcome :)